# Replacing spout on irregular bathtub pipe

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I am trying to replace a bathtub diverter spout. When I took off the old spout, I discovered it was incorrectly installed. It didn't have the common plastic adapter, the shower spout was just slipped over the end of the protruding threadless pipe.

At some point, someone extended the pipe with a slip coupling, so the pipe isn't a standard 1/2" all the way down (see below). Because the coupling makes the pipe wider, I can't slide the 3.5" long plastic adapter over the pipe.

I assume the pipe will have to be modified to accept a spout correctly. What are my best options here?

[image: pipe problem]

Comment: I have never seen a tub spout installation with a slip over plastic sleeve. What seals between the 3.5" long plastic adapter and the copper tube? Would this type have a central diverter valve inside the wall?

Comment: @jim-stewart: Like this: http://www.lasco.net/tub-spout-parts-c-2937_316_757/slip-fit-plastic-adapter-only-p-7476.html#.WvSsodMvx24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably just need to move the coupler further back. It could actually extend into the wall, and you could sweat the joint from the inside.

You could also use an "inside" pipe extension ([example](https://hdsupplysolutions.com/shop/p/1-2-copper-tube-size-extension-nipple-adapter-package-of-5-p845044)). The reduction in diameter probably isn't a concern in this case.

[image]

Comment: Turns out that Sioux Chief adapter didn't fit inside my pipe. Ended up having to hire a plumber...